# Search and replace sub array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, replace

I need to perform `Search and Replace` a sub array. This is my code

```
Dim IntegerArray() As Int32 = {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
                               1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
                               1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Specifically, I need to search `2, 0, 0, 0, 1` elements in the array and replace each one to 5

Here is the picture for the array

[image: integer array]

How to perform the `search and replace` job?

NOTE: I tried looping through the array, but to identify 5 element values is very tricky and so far I still can't make it works. Are there any .NET built-in functions that able to do the job or any smart solutions to it?

Comment: Your code so far just declares the array.  What did you try in your loop?

Comment: @DanPuzey I used 5 variables to store the most recent iterations but somehow I can't locate its original indexes to do the replace jobs

Comment: is this really hard to code? two for loops should do the job. inner for loop checks for the pattern and outer iterates over original array.

Comment: @Ankush Please share your looping solution. Maybe I can learn a thing or two from you!

Comment: @Teen Added my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

**myArray is array of integers**

*Solution*

```
String.Join(";", myArray).Replace("2;0;0;0;1", "5;5;5;5;5").Split(';').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray()
```

*Explanation*

- Step 1: convert array of ints to string (with ';' as delimiter)
- Step 2: replace part of string ("2;0;0;0;1") to another value ("5;5;5;5;5")
- Step 3: convert string back to array

  ```
  Split(';').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray()
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your solution. Can you expand your solution by using Integer array?

Comment: @Teem, In my example I'm working with array of ints. I have updated my answer and add some explanation

Comment: @Dan Purzey, What is the "filth" in this context ? (sorry, but english is not my native language)

Comment: Sorry @demas - it's a sarcastic reference to your conversion of the array into a string and back again in order to solve the problem - implying that it's a "dirty" solution.  Not always a bad thing - in this case I'd say it's quite ingenious!

Comment: I have background in dynamic and functional language and very little experience in C#, so my solution can be strange :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    internal int[] Solve(int[] input, int[] pattern, int[] replace)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            bool match = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((i + j >= input.Length) || (input[i + j] != pattern[j]))
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (match)
            {
                foreach (var item in replace)
                {
                    result.Add(item);
                }

                i += (pattern.Length - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(input[i]);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```